# what does mean this code in c sharp c#

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

im trying to create Crystal Report using Csharp language and i found a lesson how to create  A crystal Replort using C# in this website

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14029/How-to-Create-a-Crystal-Report-using-C-and-MySQL

but when i try to understand the code i dont understand some line and how to update it to my case

full button Code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Mydb mysqlclass = new Mydb();
    mysqlclass.conncting();

    // here is error under fahad.conncting.createcommand();
    MySqlCommand cmd = mysqlclass.connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM admin ";
    mysqlclass.connection.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    // Create a Dataset and using DataAdapter to fill it 
    adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(); 
    adap.SelectCommand = cmd;
    CustomerDS custDB = new CustomerDS();
    custDB.Clear();
    adap.Fill(custDB, "Customers"); 

    // Create a CrystalReport1 object 
    CrystalReport1 myReport = new CrystalReport1();
    // Set the DataSource of the report 
    myReport.SetDataSource(custDB);
    // Set the Report Source to ReportView 
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReport; 
}
```

can you please expline me what dose that mean and how i can change it to my case , thanks

this what i dont understand

```
CustomerDS custDB = new CustomerDS();
custDB.Clear();
adap.Fill(custDB, "Customers");
```

Comment: What is the error given?

Comment: Well its getting some data and assigning it as `DataSource` for your Report, Can you elaborate on what you don't understand ?

Comment: Did you write the code above? if so how can you write something that you don't understand..? or did you copy paste some example until you got it to work ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're getting something along the lines of "there is already an open reader associated with the current connection", yes? If so, see the second part of the answer.

---

> this what i dont understand
>
> ```
> CustomerDS custDB = new CustomerDS();
> custDB.Clear();
> adap.Fill(custDB, "Customers");
> ```

The first line is trivial, and simply creates a new empty instance of what looks to be a "typed dataset", that has something to do with *customers*. The main thing this line tells me is that somebody is still, for whatever reason, using `DataSet`. Have mercy on them - they know not what they do.

The second line does what it sounds like; see intellisense:

> Clears the System.Data.DataSet of any data by removing all rows in all tables.

The main thing this line tells me is that whoever wrote it has forgotten that they *only just created it*, and that it doesn't contain any data yet.

The third line uses a *data adapter* to populate `custDB` with the data from a table called "Customers" (HOWEVER! the code earlier instructed it to use a very specific select command, which actually looks at a table called "admin").

---

If we instead look at the code marked `// here is error`...

```
MySqlCommand cmd = mysqlclass.connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM admin ";
mysqlclass.connection.Open();
MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

This executes a SQL query to obtain all values from a table called "admin", via the *reader* API (a forewards-only stream of row data), but then completely ignores that reader. It doesn't use it anywhere. Most notably, it also doesn't *consume* the data, nor dispose the reader. The main thing this tells me is that the author has lost track of what they were doing. That open reader will cause problems. Delete the line:

```
MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Also: look into the `using` statement.

Comment: Thanks for reply but what dose mean 
CustomerDS custDB = new CustomerDS();

what is CustomerDS ?

Comment: @user1927867 that is a type that is defined somewhere in your project. Move the caret into it and press F12. Quite likely, that is generated from the `DataSet` project-item type (which will have a `.xsd` file extension). It models a number of database tables in terms of the `DataTable` / `DataSet` API.

Comment: user1927867 if you don't understand how to instantiate an instance of a "NEW" object and or `Class` via the keyword `new` this is the least of your worries I would suggest reading the information located on this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: thanks all i will read more about it